# Why do you see 'removing additional packages' during the Ubuntu installation?

Tags: system-installation

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and was very surprised (and amused :)) about the install-window showing the status information:

> "Zusatzpakete werden entfernt"

<sub>(means something like "removing additional packages")</sub>

Seems very weird to me that in an installation, additional packages are removed...why have they been installed in first place?

Well, not that bad, i used Windows for decades now, i just had the small hope that the linux world would be a little bit saner ;D

Comment: i think web-e answer is correct however, i would love to tell you that when i installed my ubuntu nothing happened like removing packages, but still not sure cause i sometimes leave the computer installing and also i would love to tell you that linux is amazing, powerful, customizable and beautiful :)
and you wont find any OS better than linux in programming, hacking or similar things :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TLDR; It's basically just a `apt-get autoremove` performed after installation.

Here's what happens on installation time using a *desktop* installer (this answer is not valid for *server* or *alternate* installers):

1. A sort of preinstalled Ubuntu image (`/casper/filesystem.squashfs` on the CD) is extracted onto your hard drive. It's like taking a shortcut, because it's all in a predefined state and does not require all packages to be installed one by one (opposed to the `debootstrap` process in the server/alternate installers).
2. After extraction of the image, the installer `chroot`s into the target and will apply all changes you entered during installation: user account, language, timezone, etc. It will then also apply updates.
3. The state of the target filesystem (almost finished installation) after all this will probably result in some packages not needed for your system. E.g. older kernel that is not applicable anymore due to updates, or you didn't choose to use LVM so all packages related to that can be removed. (this is just hypothetical - I did not check if this actually performs the removal of LVM.) It's not much different from applying a large stack of package updates that result in some packages removed using `apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: I can vouch that the installer removes LVM if you choose not to use it.

Comment: As I'm writing, I am waiting for an Ubuntu installation to finish. (I chose "minimal"). The process of removing packages takes way, way longer than the rest of the implementation. I wonder whether this is something that can be improved.

Answer (score 4):

Though there can be several reason, I think those packages were removed as they are unneeded now. They are installed because they were on the installation media. Now new updates came in and mark those item as not required. So ubuntu is removing it.

Another reason could be, for installation purpose ubuntu installed some packages  which are not used for normal day to day usage. So it is cleaning them up.

Answer (score 4):

There are packages present on the Live CD image which may get uninstalled after the image is copied to your hard drive. One example I can think of is gparted, it is present on the Live CD session but not available on a newly installed system. Other packages that this occurs with are usually filesystem related, for example LVM is present on the Live CD in case you want to use LVM partitioning on your installation. If you don't use this then there is no reason to have the LVM package on your installed system so it is removed. I think that the unused language packs get removed as well.

Comment: This is not exactly true. Packages like gparted are run from the live image, and not installed or.uninstalled. If they are uninstalled from the live image, you would not see them on next boot with the image.