# Can I leave GParted on a system after installation?

Tags: gparted, ubiquity

Is it possible to leave Gparted on the system after installation, seeing as it is already on the LiveUSB? As a related question, why is it removed from the final system in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user320 explained, you can install GParted through the Software Center or `sudo apt-get install gparted`. As for your second question, I believe the reason why GParted is not a part of the final installation is because Canonical decided to go with Disk Utility, which is a lighter version of GParted. The idea is to give the end user direct and clear access to simple but effective utilities; providing them with power tools from the get go can be confusing and maybe even dangerous. Power users, on the other hand, can find those power tools on their own.

It's basically the same rationale that made them let go of Synaptic in favor of a more pumped-up Software Center. Back in the day, both Synaptic and GParted were default applications.

Comment: +1 for your complete description. but I don't think `Disks` is lighter than gparted!! Others look fine..

Comment: You cannot use gparted on mounted system, so you cannot use it on  a one drive install typically. But you can use it on other drives from your install. I just install Saucy and it shows it uninstalling gparted along with a lot of other things not used in my install like RAID, lvm2 and many others.

Answer (score 1):

Gparted isn't installed as part of the installation process, unless you have a customized image you're installing with. You can either install it through the terminal or The Software Center.

***Using the Command Line***

Open the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

to launch it.

```
sudo gparted
```

***Software Center***

Just search for 'gparted' and install, thats it.

[image]

Thanks to Thomas W.

Comment: Gparted isn't installed as part of the installation process, unless you have a customized image you're installing with.  They'll have to most likely install it with `sudo apt-get install gparted` after they've installed.

Answer (score 0):

Gparted is not removed, it is just not installed. Now in 2018 see it with Ubuntu Studio 18 and Linux Mint 18.

The system is better when you try it then when you install it. Familiar thing from ads business, I myself is puzzled why it is the same with Ubuntu here...

Comment: Technically I think it is removed. See https://askubuntu.com/a/324317/158442 for more on how the installation proceeds. Around the end, GParted, and some other packages (like unnecessary localization-related ones) are removed.